# añadir valor de input text a una variable javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, entrada

```
<div>

    <form name="form1" id="form1id">
    <p>coleccionador</p>
    <input type="text" id="mitexto" placeholder="escribe aqui">
    <input type="button" name="miboton " id="mybutton" value="actualizar">

</div>

var myboton =document.getElementById("mybutton");
var mitexto = document.getElementById("mitexto").value;

function descubre(){

    if(mitexto.value =="Banreservas"){

        alert("siempre contigo!!")


    }


}

myboton.addEventListener("click", descubre(), false);
```

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es que: el alert salga siempre y cuando se escriba Banresevas en el input mitexto al hacer click en myboton

Comment: Agrega tu ultimo comentario editando tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltaban tres cosas:

1. Cierra tu forma con `</form>`
2. La variable `mitexto` debe ir adentro de tu funcion.
3. La variable `mitexto` ya contiene el valor con `.value` asi que cuando comparas en el if, ya no tienes que obtener el `.value` otra vez.

```js
var myboton =document.getElementById("mybutton");


function descubre(){

    var mitexto = document.getElementById("mitexto").value;
    if(mitexto =="Banreservas"){

        alert("siempre contigo!!")


    }


}

myboton.addEventListener("click", descubre, false);
```

```html
<div>

    <form name="form1" id="form1id">
    <p>coleccionador</p>
    <input type="text" id="mitexto" placeholder="escribe aqui">
    <input type="button" name="miboton " id="mybutton" value="actualizar">
    </form>

</div>
```